# Call a boost function without callback

Tags: c++, websocket, boost-beast, beast, beast-websockets

I am using boost-beast library for a websocket connection.
You can refer to [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async-ssl/websocket_client_async_ssl.cpp) for the **understanding** what is happening. I have used the same example, but changed a few things:

- split the `on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)` into three functions `A(beast::error_code ec)`,`B(beast::error_code ec)` and `C(beast::error_code ec)`
- `B()` sends binary data, and `A()` and `C()` are sending text.
- `A()` calls `B()` as callback and `B()` calls `C()` as callback.

Now I am stuck at a point where I want to do this:

```
void session::A(beast::error_code ec) {
    if (ec)
        return (fail(ec, "handshake"));

    ws_.async_write(net::buffer(SOMETEXT),bind(&session::B, shared_from_this(), placeholders::_1));

}
void session::B(beast::error_code ec) {
    if (ec)
        return (fail(ec, "A_FAILED"));

    if(condition1) {
        ws_.binary(true);
        ws_.async_write(net::buffer(SOMEBINARY),bind(&session::C, shared_from_this(), placeholders::_1));
    } else {
        session::on_write(ec,<WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE>);
    }

}
void session::C(beast::error_code ec) {
    if (ec)
        return (fail(ec, "B_FAILED"));

    ws_.binary(false);

    ws_.async_write(net::buffer(SOMETEXT),bind(&session::on_write, shared_from_this(), placeholders::_1, placeholders::_2));

}
```

Here is the **Read** function:

```
void
on_write(
    beast::error_code ec,
    std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    if(ec)
        return fail(ec, "write");

    // Read a message into our buffer
    ws_.async_read(
        buffer_,
        std::bind(
            &session::on_read,
            shared_from_this(),
            std::placeholders::_1,
            std::placeholders::_2));
}
```

**QUESTION:-** Please check the function `B()` and my question there. Any advice or answer is appreciated.

Comment: `session::on_write(ec, 0 /* field unused */);` ?

Comment: @hare1039 Please put it as answer, so that I can close the question :) It worked.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just put a `0` in the argument and mark it as unused

e.g. `session::on_write(ec, 0 /* field unused */);`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can give your function signatures default parameters:

```
void session::B(
    beast::error_code ec = {},
    std::size_t bytes_transferred = 0);
```